# How to use class abstraction with JDL?

Tags: postgresql, jhipster, jdl

I'm doing a project for my last year of university.

I have to make a commercial website using JHipster (in my case Angluar + Spring + PostgreSQL).

Using JDL, I figured out that abstract classes seems to not be supported, therefore it seems impossible to use inheritance. Do you know how to bypass this issue?

Here is the jdl : [https://framabin.org/p/?0ec3f3890f12aded#Xum+8i00kbP8p2jGhIVSXgu3Twc8BdwJ5iJ5t6cM/7A=](https://framabin.org/p/?0ec3f3890f12aded#Xum%208i00kbP8p2jGhIVSXgu3Twc8BdwJ5iJ5t6cM/7A=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found out there's no support for inheritance in JHipster generated entities, so either you code it manually using [Hibernate strategies](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance)  or by [replacing inheritance by composition](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/composition-vs-inheritance-jpa-hibernate/) which is often a good idea.

You could also compose by using one-to-one relationships and using DTOs to present joined entities as a single object.

In any case, you'll probably going to modify substantially the generated views in Angular code.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. Indeed I'll use Hibernate strategies. I modified my database diagram to do so. I wonder if Inheritance will be supported in the future by JHipster for generated entities

Comment: It's very unlikely that JHipster supports inheritance in the future because dev team favors composition over inheritance which is also what most people do.